# Test if argument is inside domain of InterpolatingFunction

Tags: interpolation

[The documentation says](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html#25883) *In standard output format, only the domain element of an InterpolatingFunction object is printed explicitly. The remaining elements are indicated by <>*

But this is not the same as the actual domain where it doesn't use extrapolated values, see this example with a $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function:

```
SeedRandom[1];
dat = RandomReal[1, {9, 3}];
paramdat = Map[{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[3]]} &, dat];

ip = Interpolation[paramdat, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0.128821,0.825163},{0.11142,0.925275}},<>] *)

ip["Domain"]
(* {{0.128821, 0.825163}, {0.11142, 0.925275}} *)

{x, y} = {0.12887062309893396`, 0.11147780180592484`};

ip[[1, 1, 1]] < x < ip[[1, 1, 2]] && ip[[1, 2, 1]] < y < ip[[1, 2, 2]]
(* True *)

ip[x, y];
(* InterpolatingFunction::dmval:
   "Input value {0.128871,0.111478} lies outside the range of data in the
    interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."
*)
```

Is there a way to get the actual domain of an `InterpolatingFunction`?

(and can I see all possible `ip["something"]`, I only found "Domain" by chance)

Comment: Take a look at the package ``<< DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` ``.  It's documented in the advanced NDSolve docs, and if you look at the package source, you'll find all these `ip["something"]` things.  The package is simply a wrapper over these.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, that was an easy read :)

Comment: `InterpolatingFunction` itself did not seem very well documented. That documentation wasn't linked either. So unless I were using `NDSolve` or looking here, that would have been hard to find.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to create a function that uses `Check` to see if the message was printed.

```
InDomainQ[ip_,x_]:=Quiet[Check[ip@@x;True,False,InterpolatingFunction::dmval]]
```

For the function in the question:

```
region = RegionPlot[InDomainQ[ip,{x,y}],
    {x,ip[[1,1,1]],ip[[1,1,2]]},
    {y,ip[[1,2,1]],ip[[1,2,2]]},
    MaxRecursion->4,
    PlotPoints->50,
    Epilog->{Red,Point[{x,y}]}]
```

[image: region]

This seems to be the convex hull of the points:

```
<<ComputationalGeometry`
hullpts = ip["Grid"][[ConvexHull[ip["Grid"]]]]
hull = Graphics[{
   {Red, Point[{x, y}]},
   {Opacity[0.2], Green, Polygon[hullpts]}
   }];
Show[region, hull]
```

[image: hull]

But how often this is the case I don't know.

**Edit:** For functions $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ it actually seems the idea of using the convex hull to determine the domain is more reliable than checking for the message

```
SeedRandom[1];
dat = RandomReal[1, {9, 4}];
paramdat = Map[{Most[#], Last[#]} &, dat];
ip = Interpolation[paramdat, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

`ip[10000,0,0]` is clearly outside the domain but does not trigger a message, and checking that the argument is inside the rectangle given by `ip["Domain"]` would only be partially helpful.

```
InDomainQ[ip_InterpolatingFunction, x_List] := 
 Quiet[Check[ip @@ x; True, False, InterpolatingFunction::dmval], 
  InterpolatingFunction::dmval]

(* Plot InDomainQ region together with convex hull *)
d = 0.05;
pts = Select[
   Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, 0, 1, d}, {y, 0, 1, d}, {z, 0, 1, d}],2],
   (InDomainQ[ip, #] &)
   ];

(* ConvexHull3D is in MathWorldPackages.zip
available at http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4775 *)
hull = ConvexHull3D[ip["Grid"]];

Graphics3D[{
  {Green, Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[Opacity[0.3]], 
   Cuboid[# - d/2, # + d/2] & /@ pts},
  {Blue, Sphere[ip["Grid"], 0.05]},
  {Opacity[0.3], hull}
  }]
```

[image: 3d Hull]

Green is where `InDomainQ` is `True`. The blue spheres is the domain part of the interpolated points, and the polygons connecting them form their convex hull.

Since `ComplexHull3D` returns such nicely oriented `Polygons` it's easy to construct a new `InDomainQ` function simply by checking if the signed distance  from a given point to each polygon has the same sign:

```
(* pt's side of the plane passing through the p1,p2,p3 *)
SideOfPlane[{p1_,p2_,p3_},pt_]:=Module[
  {v1=p2-p1,v2=p3-p1,n},
  n=Cross[v1,v2];
  Sign[n.(pt-p1)]
]

GetDomainFunction[ip_]:=Module[
  { hull=ConvexHull3D[ip["Grid"]], planes},
  planes=hull/.Polygon[a_]:>a;
  (* Here is where the orientation from ConvexHull3D comes in
     if the sign from SideOfPlane is same for all the polygons
     it is in the convex hull *)
  Function[{x,y,z},Evaluate[
   Equal@@Function[plane,SideOfPlane[plane,{x,y,z}]]/@planes
  ]]
];

(* InDomainQ[x,y,z], only for this instance of ip *)
InDomainQ=GetDomainFunction[ip];

hull = ConvexHull3D[ip["Grid"]];
Show[{
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4],Green,hull}],
  RegionPlot3D[InDomainQ[x,y,z],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},{z,0,1},
    MaxRecursion->4,
    PlotPoints->30,
    PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.4],Blue]]
}]
```

[image: Convex hull based domain function]