# How to remove the warnings and errors from this manipulate code?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, manipulate, graphics3d, warning-messages

I'm experiencing several problems with the manipulate code below.  This code numerically solves **three first-order non-linear differential equations**, and then output a **3D plot** of the curve, using the initial conditions entered by the user from the three sliders :

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Theta1 = -20;
Theta2 = 20;

dynamics[om_, or_, ol_] := dynamics[om, or, ol] = NDSolve[{
    oM'[theta] == (oM[theta] + 2oR[theta] - 2oL[theta] - 1)oM[theta],
    oR'[theta] == (oM[theta] + 2oR[theta] - 2oL[theta] - 2)oR[theta],
    oL'[theta] == (oM[theta] + 2oR[theta] - 2oL[theta] + 2)oL[theta],

    oM[0] == om, oR[0] == or, oL[0] == ol

    }, {oM, oR, oL}, {theta, Theta1, Theta2},
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"
    (* constraints to be imposed : oM, oR, oL > 0 only *)
]

Tmin[om_, or_, ol_] := Theta1 (* to be fixed *)
Tmax[om_, or_, ol_] := Theta2 (* to be fixed *)

solution[om_, or_, ol_] := ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[{oM[theta], oR[theta], oL[theta]}/.dynamics[om, or, ol]],
    {theta, Tmin[om, or, ol], Tmax[om, or, ol]}
]

Manipulate[
    Show[
    solution[om, or, ol],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}},
    SphericalRegion -> True
    ],
    {{om, 0.3, a}, 0, 2, 0.01},
    {{or, 0.0, b}, 0, 2, 0.01},
    {{ol, 0.7, c}, 0, 2, 0.01}
]
```

At compilation, I'm getting several error messages that I don't know how to solve.  The manipulate box should be regular for all values entered from the sliders (from 0 up to 2 or more), especially when any of the variables is set to 0.  The ***oM***, ***oR*** and ***oL*** variables should only be positive, so a constraint should be added to the NDSolve part, and the curve extremities should be properly defined with the ***Tmin*** and ***Tmax*** definitions above.  Currently, it doesn't work well.

How can I fix these problems ?

**EDIT :** Here are two typical messages that annoys me :

> ... step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected
>
> ... lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

Comment: You only get errors like `InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {-20.} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. "`, right? Or other errors? Always state _what the errors are_ in the OP.

Comment: Also, since this is an initial value problem, why don't you specify the function value at the **initial** points, e.g. `oM[Theta1] == om`?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, there are several sorts of warning or errors while compilating this code.  Yes, I want to prevent any extrapolation.  Also, I can't use **oM[Theta1] == om** since the "initial" conditions are defined specifically at **theta = 0**, and I need to get the curve on both sides : **theta < 0** (backward in time) and **theta > 0** (forward in time).

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91268/4999 -- Alternatively, stay within the domain.

Comment: Please include the message name too (`NDSolve::ndsz` or whatever they are). It's useful for searching. -- The first one can be taken care of with `Quiet[..., NDSolve::ndsz]` or whatever, assuming it blows up in finite time, which is not an error.

Comment: How can I find the extremities of the curve, without any extrapolation ?  How to properly define the end parameters **Tmin[om, or, ol]** and **Tmax[om, or, ol]** ?

Comment: See [(87525)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87525). Also [(28337)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28337). These, too, are related: [(15953)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15953), [(20774)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20774).

Comment: @MichaelE2, sorry, these questions/answers aren't helping me.  I need to solve this issue :  how to properly define the argument (**theta min** and **theta max**) of both extremities of the curve, to remove the extrapolation warning ?

Comment: Both problems are solve in [(87525)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87579).

Comment: @MichaelE2, well, I don't understand that answer.  Please, could you be more specific, and apply your solution as an answer here ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm leaving on a trip in a few minutes.  The key things are `"Domain"` and `"ExtrapolationHandler"` in that post.  You can also find them in other posts.  Maybe someone else will come along in the meantime.

Comment: Does `Dynamic\Manipulate` have anything to do with the question? Can you pose a specific example with specific parameters that demonstrate the error in a more simple way?

Comment: @george2079, already at compilation of the code above, I'm getting several messages, starting with this : **Input value [19.9983] lies
outside the range of data in the interpolating function.
Extrapolation will be used.**  As soon as I move a bit one of the sliders, I may get more messages, and some like this : **At theta == 0.402456, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.** (try these inputs : **a = 1.49**, **b = 1.05** and **c = 0.06**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit of an extended comment, this is a minimal demonstration of the error you see.
(You should have posted something like this to begin with)
Note dynamic/manipulate has nothing to do with it, nor does the initial condition being in the middle of the domain cause the problem.

```
r = With[{om = 1, or = 2, ol = .3}, First@NDSolve[{
      oM'[ theta] == (oM[theta] + 2 oR[theta] - 2 oL[theta] - 1) oM[theta],
      oR'[theta] == (oM[theta] + 2 oR[theta] - 2 oL[theta] - 2) oR[theta],
      oL'[theta] == (oM[theta] + 2 oR[theta] - 2 oL[theta] + 2) oL[theta],
      oM[0] == om, oR[0] == or, oL[0] == ol},
     {oM, oR, oL},
     {theta, 0, 2}]];
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At theta == 0.35134263731177495`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

```
Plot[{(oR /. r)[x], (oM /. r)[x], (oL /. r)[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0,40}]
```

[image]

the pde is simply blowing up.

increasing `ol` to .4 yields a stable solution:

[image]

Now that we see whats going on, go back to `Manpulate`, adding `Quiet` to surpress the error and extract the valid range from each solution:

```
Manipulate[
 Quiet[
  r = With[{om = 1, or = 2}, First@NDSolve[{
       oM'[theta] == (oM[theta] + 2 oR[theta] - 2 oL[theta] - 1) oM[
          theta],
       oR'[theta] == (oM[theta] + 2 oR[theta] - 2 oL[theta] - 2) oR[
          theta],
       oL'[theta] == (oM[theta] + 2 oR[theta] - 2 oL[theta] + 2) oL[
          theta],
       oM[0] == om, oR[0] == or, oL[0] == ol},
      {oM, oR, oL},
      {theta, 0, 2}]]];
  range = Flatten[(oM /. r)["Domain"]];
  Plot[{(oR /. r)[x], (oM /. r)[x], (oL /. r)[x]}, 
      Evaluate[Join[{x}, range]], PlotRange -> {0, 40}],
{{ol, .4}, .3, 1}]
```

Finally, fixing the original should look like this:

```
solution[om_, or_, ol_] := (
  result = Quiet@First@dynamics[om, or, ol];
  range = (oM /. result)["Domain"][[1]];
  ParametricPlot3D[{oM[theta], oR[theta], oL[theta]} /. result, 
   Evaluate[Join[{theta}, range]]])
```

Comment: I'm not sure it should blow up or not.  My 3D graphics is okay, but the numerical resolution should stop if there's really a blow up, and the **Tmin**, **Tmax** should take care of it.  What do you mean by "increasing **ol** to .4" ?

Comment: see edit, I show how to get the valid range from the solution in case where it blows up.

Comment: With your last code, I'm getting this error message : **Join::heads: Heads List and MinMax at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.**

Comment: `MinMax` is a new function (v10.1), for older versions do: `range = (Flatten[(oM /. r)["Grid"]])[[{1, -1}]]` .. actually using "Domain" is even better, I updated the code to use that.

Comment: Yep, this last one works very well.  Now I'm not sure to understand your code.  How do I change my limits **Tmin** and **Tmax** in my code above ?

Comment: see last edit..

Comment: It's working great.  Sadly, I don't understand that solution !  :-(

Comment: While I'm not understanding clearly your last code, I may adopt it anyway since it appears to work flawlesly.  I'll wait a bit before marking your answer, since others may have another solution, easier to understand for me.